# Methods of extending the monthly data to daily data and the reliability of interpolated values

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation, missing-data

The project is about detecting the co-exceedances among different markets. Daily data for the bond, stock and gold are available, but not for the real-estate (low liquidity). The chain relative ratio of the housing price is collected monthly, specifically, the price is only detected on the last day of each month. However, for detecting the count of co-exceedances, the monthly data is obviously not enough and we need to extend the size of it.

I have tried some interpolation methods, like linear, cubic spline and Kalman (StructTS, not ARIMA). They truly returned interpolated values, but too smooth. If we treat the house/real estate as a commodity in the market, volatility should exist. How to add the volatility to the interpolated values? I also need to know the reliability of the interpolation because there are too many missing data being replaced.

The original data frame of housing price ratio is

```
    dput(house.dat)
    structure(list(Time = structure(c(14790, 14821, 14852, 14882, 
    14913, 14943, 14974, 15005, 15033, 15064, 15094, 15125, 15155, 
    15186, 15217, 15247, 15278, 15308, 15339, 15370, 15399, 15430, 
    15460, 15491, 15521, 15552, 15583, 15613, 15644, 15674, 15705, 
    15736, 15764, 15795, 15825, 15856, 15886, 15917, 15948, 15978, 
    16009, 16039, 16070, 16101, 16129, 16160, 16190, 16221, 16251, 
    16282, 16313, 16343, 16374, 16404, 16435, 16466, 16494, 16525, 
    16555, 16586, 16616, 16647, 16678, 16708, 16739, 16769, 16800, 
    16831, 16860, 16891, 16921, 16952, 16982, 17013, 17044, 17074, 
    17105, 17135), class = "Date"), housing.index = c(0.88, -1.3775, 
    -0.7775, 1.695, 0.95, 0.9625, 0.9975, 1.94, 1.1925, 0.6875, 0.5175, 
    0.6875, 0.3775, 0.625, -0.1225, -0.2525, -0.336, -0.24825, -0.588, 
    -0.08375, -0.16725, -0.341, -0.637, -0.408, 0.33325, 0.29, 0.34225, 
    0.30325, 0.38, 0.36, 0.69625, 1.6675, 1.8625, 1.16, 0.995, 1.095, 
    1.2425, 1.195, 1.1725, 1.5425, 1.895, 1.5675, 1.5075, 0.775, 
    0.6775, 0.4325, 0.3175, -0.305, -0.51, -0.94, -0.6975, -1.0175, 
    -0.6925, 0.47, 0.035, 0.3, 0.215, -0.1875, 0.2225, 1.305, 2.02, 
    2.8425, 1.26, 0.9075, 0.84, 0.9775, 1.68, 1.5925, 1.585, 2.7725, 
    1.925, 1.8475, 1.37, 1.7775, 2.62, 3.025, 1.4325, 0.9625)), .Names 
    = c("Time", 
    "housing.index"), row.names = c(NA, 78L), class = "data.frame")
```

The NA has been added to the daily frame, the following only shows the first thirty-three lines of the new data frame.

```
     daily.df[c(1:33),]
         Time housing.index
    1  2010-06-30        0.8800
    2  2010-07-01            NA
    3  2010-07-02            NA
    4  2010-07-03            NA
          ...               ...

    28 2010-07-27            NA
    29 2010-07-28            NA
    30 2010-07-29            NA
    31 2010-07-30            NA
    32 2010-07-31       -1.3775
    33 2010-08-01            NA
```

Many thanks if you have some clues or tips for my problem.

Comment: This isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need help choosing a statistical model for your data, you should be asking for help at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on-topic.